# Remove Duplicates From One List

Tags: code-golf, array, counting

### Task:

Remove all duplicates from one list of integers. A list is simply a sequence of connected values that allows the same values to be stored at different positions in this sequence.

If an item was found to be the same value as another item in this list, keep the first occurence of the item and remove the second (third and so on...) occurence of the item.

### Input/Output

You may write a function or full program that takes a list of integers as an input and returns a list without duplicates as an output.

### Rules:

- This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so shortest answer wins!

Comment: Please state what you mean by a "list", and how the program will interact with this list (i.e. input/output)

Comment: I would have preferred leaving this question closed and creating a new one, since it is old and the edit invalidates almost all of the existing answers

Comment: @JoKing same here. I have no idea why/who reopened, but I thought it was best to clean it up if it was being reopened

Answer (score 4):

### APL (1)

```
∪
```

`∪` takes a list and returns the unique elements  in a list, i.e.:

```
    ∪ 1 2 3 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

if you need I/O it's 2:

```
∪⎕
```

Comment: Since it's not specified, default counting for code-golf is in bytes (according to the tag wiki), which would make `∪` 2 (UTF-16) or 3 (UTF-8) bytes. Together with I/O, that's 4 or 6.

Answer (score 3):

### GolfScript (2 bytes)

```
.&
```

Takes input on stack, leaves output on stack.

Comment: GolfScript beats all!as usual...

Answer (score 1):

## Red, 8 bytes

```
unique s
```

assuming list is in word 's

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2: 12 bytes

```
print set(l)
```

No input spec, so I'm assuming the list is held in a variable called `l`.

Answer (score 0):

## Python - 12 bytes

```
list(set(l))
```

Assuming the list is given in the variable `l`.

Answer (score 0):

### Mathematica, 7 bytes or 3 characters

Assumes input in variable `x`

```
Union@x
```

If we're counting in Mathematica characters, I can do 3 (the second input line):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 3 characters

```
a|a
```

Assumes the list is stored in variable `a`. Also works with `&` instead of `|`.

If the original list has to be altered (instead of keeping the original the same and creating a new list with duplicates removed), then 4 characters:

```
a|=a
```